# Submit form twice or refresh two times

Tags: php, javascript, forms, webforms, form-submit

Hi I am using php and i want to submit form on `onclick` event of radio button.
when form submission is done, than after I want to reload my page.

Means first form is submitted and after form submit I want to reload my page again.

Is it possible?

I have tried it with javascript but not get any idea how to do it..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<form action='#'>` should do that for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header('Location: http://url.to/reload');
exit;
```

Make sure to do this **before any output on that page** otherwise you'll get an error about headers already having been sent.

Comment: Ideas : i am submitting form using javascript and after submitting form i want ot reload my page again.

Comment: If you have the submission form bit completed, the above code will reload your page. You need to put that code in your form handling PHP page and replace 'http://url.to/reload' with your page url.